# Python taking arguments

Tags: python, file-io, sys

I am trying to deal with optional command line input files, and based on whether or not there is a file to read in, set values to either what is in the file or default values. How do I set up Python to check to see if there is an argument to take in from command line? I have what is below, but the problem is is when I run my program with "python myPythonScript.py", it still evaluates as if there is a file to read in, when I never piped in a file.

```
import sys
value1 = 0
value2 = 0


if len(sys.argv) >= 1):
    with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    //file opens here and I take the contents and set values 1 and 2
    //based on the input 

else:
    //values are set to default values that I define here
```

Comment: have you tried printing `sys.argv` ?

Comment: `len(sys.argv) >= 1` will _always_ be true, as the program itself is the first argument.

Comment: you may also want to check out the argparse package, that does handles very nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
if len(sys.argv) >= 1:
```

with:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
```

If you run your script as `python myPythonScript.py`, `len(sys.argv)` is `1`.  This is because program name itself is the first argument. So you may need to check if `len` is `> 1` to check for optional arguments from command line.

Comment: I replaced it and piped in a file with '<' but it did not fix the issue. I have print statements saying the script name, the number of arguments and what they are and they say that my script is "myPythonScript.py", number of args is 1, and that "the arguments are 'myPythonScript.py' ". This was both piping in the file and not. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Run your script as 'python myPythonScript.py filename' and in your script use `sys.arg[1]` to get the name filename. Use that in `open` to open file.

Comment: Yes, that was the thing that I needed. Awesome, thanks a heap.